# Строка подключения SqlConnection

Tags: c#

Имеется следующий код по вставке новой записи в БД:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection sqlConnection1 =
            new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:/BD.mdb");

            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT ThemeTest (Id_theme, NameTheme, NumberQuestion, Prim) VALUES"+
                "(@Id_theme , @NameTheme, @NumberQuestion, @Prim)";
            cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_theme", 5);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NameTheme", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NumberQuestion", numericUpDown1.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prim", textBox2.Text);
            sqlConnection1.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Ругается на строку подключения: " Ключевое слово не поддерживается provide". Что я делаю не правильно? Как правильно написать строку подключения к локальной таблице на access?

Comment: Может быть это поможет, здесь пример: https://youtu.be/_4IP9gAhN8w

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для Access надо использовать OleDbConnection. SqlConnection - это для MSSQL сервера.
[Пруф](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms254500.aspx).

Строка у вас верная, но если есть какие-то сомнения или подключение будет настраиваться в программе используйте [OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder.aspx). [Здесь](http://connectionstrings.com/access) примеры строк подключения в разных ситуациях.

Comment: Кто-нибудь может тогда написать пример для access базы. Вставку новой записи, например... Очень хочется в готовом варианте увидеть все это.

Comment: Ну вроде только это и поменять осталось, должно заработать.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand замените на System.Data.SqlClient.OleDbConnection, будет работать (проверить негде сорри).