# Как записать данные из базы в переменную?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Допустим у меня есть таблица `objects` с 1 столбцом `Objnumber` где значения `object1`, `object2`...
Я хочу записывать с помощью цикла все значения по очереди в 1 переменную (string name). Как мне это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста.
Класс для подключения:

```
internal class ConnectionDB
{
    SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection("Строка подключения");

    public void opnenConnection()
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
        }
    }
    public void closeConnection()
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
    public SqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        return sqlConnection;
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вы не понимаете, как взаимодействовать с бд, вот пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1058250/378277 или https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/101701/378277. Не совсем понятно, в чём возникает проблема. Вы не можете подключить к бд из-за какой-то ошибки? Не получается создать запрос в базу данных? Добавьте в вопрос чуть конкретики

Comment: Я уже неоднократно спрашивал у других, ответа ни разу не получил. Зачем вы создаёте такой, по сути, бесполезный класс-обёртку для SqlConnection? Этому учат в каком-то учебном заведении? В каком? Так написано в каком-то туториале (видеокурсе)? В каком? Хотелось бы посмотреть в глаза автору сего непотребства и _[вырезано цензурой]_

Comment: @Frehzy, ошибки нигде нет, все подключается и нормально работает, у меня получилось изменять и додавать данные в базу. Суть в том что я хочу еще и получить данные и не в datagrig, а переменную. А класс я навел так как подумал что тоже нужно показать, хотя проблема не в нем.

Comment: @Mekisym Значит проблема в том, как конвертировать данные из datagrid в какой list<t>. Воспользуйтесь рефлексией. Алгоритм следующий: создаёте класс, аналогичный вашей таблице. Название столбца в datagrid соответствует названию свойства. Если такое свойство есть, то устанавливаете для него значение. Так проходитесь по всем строкам

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чтобы в этих классах были методы для работы с бд. чтобы запрос на селект какой-то бд не писать по новой, не конвертить в какой-то класс итп...

Comment: @Aarnihauta - против правильных классов с реально полезной функциональностью я не возражаю. А против текущего убожества - да.

Answer (score 2):

Очень часто в коде новичков я встречал классы, наподобие вашего. По сути, это бесполезный класс-обёртка для `SqlConnection`.

Как выглядит использование вашего класса:

```
var db = new ConnectionDB(); // создаём экземпляр класса
db.openConnection(); // открываем соединение
...db.getConnection()... // получаем и как-то используем соединение
db.closeConnection(); // закрываем соединение
```

Как выглядит использование стандартного класса:

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString); // создаём экземпляр класса
conn.Open(); // открываем соединение
...conn... // как-то используем соединение
conn.Close(); // закрываем соединение
```

То же самое! 4 строки.
Так зачем нужна эта обёртка `ConnectionDB`?

---

Кроме того, при работе с БД может произойти какая-либо ошибка, в результате выполнение не дойдёт до строки закрытия соединения. Оно останется в подвешенном состоянии.

В вашем коде это можно решить следующим образом:

```
ConnectionDB db = null;
try
{
    db = new ConnectionDB();
    db.openConnection();
    ...db.getConnection()...
}
finally
{
    db?.closeConnection();
}
```

Громоздко, не правда ли?

А при использовании стандартного `SqlConnection` это делается так:

```
using var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
...conn...
```

И это всё! Всего лишь добавили `using`. При этом убрав вызов `Close`. Код получился короче и полностью гарантирует очистку ресурсов даже в случае выброса исключения.

Такое возможно потому, что `SqlConnection` реализует интерфейс `IDisposable`.
Этот интерфейс можно реализовать и в вашем классе, но зачем? Это не прибавит ни капельки удобства/надёжности/лаконичности.

---

И я чуть не забыл о ещё одной важной детали - асинхронности!
Стандартные классы `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataReader` имеют асинхронные методы: `OpenAsync()` и пр.
При использовании вашего класса эти методы становятся недоступны.

Answer (score 1):

Пример реализации:

```
internal static class Converter
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this DataTable dataTable)
    {
        var objType = typeof(T);
        var properties = objType.GetProperties();

        var list = new List<T>();
        foreach (var row in dataTable.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var instance = (T)Convert.ChangeType(Activator.CreateInstance(objType), typeof(T));
            foreach (var prop in properties)
            { 
                var index = dataTable.Columns.IndexOf(prop.Name);
                if (index < 0)
                    continue;

                var item = row.ItemArray[index];
                prop.SetValue(instance, Convert.ChangeType(item, prop.PropertyType));
            }
            list.Add(instance);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Допустим, у вас есть таблица, в которой есть 2 столбца: Id(int), Name(text). Создаёте класс по аналогии:

```
public class SomeTable
{
    public int Id { get; set;} 

    public string Name { get; set;} 

    public SomeTable() {} 
}
```

Получаете datatable из запроса и делаете следующее:

```
var list = myDt.ToEnumerable<SomeTable>()
```