# Исключение типа "Заданное приведение является недопустимым"

Tags: c#, winforms, исключения

Хочу взять данные из двух столбцов БД, выполнить с ними расчеты и занести в график.

```
string sql = "Select * From Детали";

db.OpenConnection();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, db.getConnection());
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int type = reader.GetInt32(3);
    int kol = reader.GetInt32(6);

    int sum = type * kol;

    cartesianChart1.Series = new SeriesCollection
    {
        new LineSeries
        {
            Values = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>
            {
                new ObservablePoint (0, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (2, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (4, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (6, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum),
                new ObservablePoint (8, sum)
            },
            PointGeometrySize = 15
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: И? Вы не задали вопрос.

Comment: В какой строке ошибка - надо догадаться?

Comment: _Тяжело вздыхает..._ Опять я вижу никчёмный класс `db` с методами `OpenConnection`, `getConnection`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217 - тут я расписал, почему такой класс-обёртка ненужен и вреден.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну если учесть, что в винформах никто с БД не работает кроме учеников, то данный класс - не самое страшное. Ведь потом эти люди приходят и спрашивают, как им сделать чтобы с базой больше одного клиента могло работать. Отвечаешь, что нужно сервер писать - а в ответ много удивления. А как узнают про EF, так вообще мир перестает быть прежним. Как это приложение само таблицы создает? В смысле "вообще не надо писать SQL запросы"? :)