# Как удалить данные из таблицы MySql?

Tags: c#, mysql

Вопрос такой, есть код добавления данных в БД MySQL. Как мне удалить определенную строку по "id_product". Допустив ввожу в окно textbox9 число 1, нажимаю на button4 и удаляется строка под id_product = 1. Из БД "shop", таблицы "products".

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Введите наименование товара");
        return;
    }
    if (textBox2.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Введите цену товара");
        return;
    }

    DB db = new DB();

    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO products (`name`, `price`, `proizv`, `color`, `amount`) VALUES(@name, @price, @proizv, @color, @amount)", db.getConnection());

    command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@price", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@proizv", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox3.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@color", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox4.Text;
    command.Parameters.Add("@amount", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;

    db.openConnection();

    if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
    MessageBox.Show("Товар добавлен");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Товар не добавлен");

    db.closeConnection();
}
```

Код с Delete. Не могу подправить его под свой интерфейс приложения

```
private void DeleteRow(string idproduct)
{
    string conStr = "datasource=127.0.0.1;port=3306;username=root;database=shop;";
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        try
        {
            //параметризованный запрос
            string sql = "DELETE FROM user " +
            "WHERE id_product = @id_product";
            //открываем соединение с базой данных
            con.Open();
            //создаём команду
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, con);
            //создаем параметр и добавляем его в коллекцию
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id_product", idproduct);
            //выполняем sql запрос
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text))
    {
        DeleteRow(textBox9.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: [Delete](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)?

Comment: Вы метки наугад ставите?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217 - про бесполезный класс `DB`

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Добавил код с Delete в описание, но ошибку найти не могу

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Очень полезная ссылка, как раз под мой вопрос

Comment: `delete from products ` - нэ?

Comment: Имя параметра `@id_product`, а не `@LastName`

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov delete from products это понятно, но суть в том, что я не понимаю как привязать кнопку button4_click и окно ввода textbox9, чтобы при вводе цифры 1, из базы данных удалялась именно строка с id_product 1.

Comment: Приведённый вами код делает именно это.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov к сожалению это не так, есть у меня подозрения, что ошибка где-то тут
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox9.Text))
    {
        DeleteRow(textBox9.Text);
    }

Comment: Судя по всему команда удаляет данные из таблицы, а также пытается это сделать еще и из textbox9.text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почему вот из user удаляете?

```
string sql = "DELETE FROM user " +
            "WHERE id_product = @id_product";
```

Comment: DELETE FROM имя_таблицы;
Разве не так ?

Comment: так, но вы же написали в постановке задачи, что удалять надо из таблицы products?

Comment: Благодарю за внимательность ! Действительно проблема была лишь в этом