# Заполнение таблицы базы данных phpmyadmin MySQL через windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, phpmyadmin

Столкнулся с такой проблемой
есть БД в phpmyadmin [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В windows форм есть кнопки добавление данных в таблицы post, pr_post

Мне необходимо сделать так, чтобы в приложении можно было добавить товар о продукте, соответственно в таблицу product. Код под кнопкой button3_Click. Но при этом чтобы можно было выбрать варианты поставщика таблица (post) и варианты продуктов поставщика таблица (pr_post). Я так понимаю это делается через элемент Combobox, но как связать данные элемент из первых двух таблиц и Combobox не до конца понимаю, необходимо чтобы работало так, выбираешь id фирмы и id продукта поставки, пишешь название товара и он добавляется в БД.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox5.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите количество товара");
            return;
        }
        
        if (textBox2.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Введите цену товара");
            return;
        }

        DB db = new DB();



        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO pr_post (`amount`, `price_post`) VALUES(@amount, @price_post)", db.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@amount", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox5.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@price_post", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox2.Text;

        db.openConnection();

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Информация о товаре поставщика добалена");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Информация о товаре поставщика не добалена");

        db.closeConnection();
    }
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        DB db = new DB();

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO product (`name`) VALUES(@name)", db.getConnection());

        command.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox7.Text;
        


        db.openConnection();

        if (command.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            MessageBox.Show("Товар добавлен");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Товар не добавлен");

        db.closeConnection();

    }
```

Comment: Так, а в чём возникает проблема? Получаем данные из таблиц post и pr_post (select запросы). Биндим их к соответствующим ComboBox. В TextBox пользователь вводит что-то, выбирает item в combobox, нажимает на кнопку - мы получает выбранные данные из ComboBox, TextBox, формируем sql insert запрос и отправляем в бд

Comment: А как вывести данные из таблицы в combobox, то, что это select запросы я разобрался
Попытался как-то так сделать, но не выходит

private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DB db = new DB();
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(("SELECT id_post, firma FROM post"), db.getConnection());
        }

Comment: 1. Что за класс `DB`? 2. Зачем вы каждый раз при срабатывании ивента SelectedIndexChanged выполняете `SELECT`? Разве это не нужно делать 1 раз в методе Form_Load? \ Алгоритм действий следующий: 1. Создаёте 2 класса Post и PR_Post, описываете в них ваши таблицы (в виде свойств). 2. Выполняете SELECT запрос в базу данных и конвертируете полученные данные в List<T>, где T - ваш класс, который вы создали выше (https://stackoverflow.com/q/20726005/13123688 как делать запросы в бд || https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1416875/378277 как конвертировать из DataTable в List<T>)....

Comment: ... 3. Создаёте BindingList<T> и вставляете в него ваши данные из List<T>. Привязываете этот BindingList к ComboBox (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6164304/13123688 как это сделать). 4. С помощью свойства SelectedItem у ComboBox получаете выбранный итем и конвертируете его в ваш класс (`(T)cmbBox.SelectedItem`). 5. Делаете INSERT запрос в базу данных для того. чтобы вставить данные (https://stackoverflow.com/q/16167924/13123688 как сделать insert запрос)