# Как подсчитать сумму по условию (SQL запрос) в Winforms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Пишу приложение на WinForms C# (.NET Framework 4.7.2), БД в MS SQL SERVER 2019.

**Моё приложение очень простое, у меня нет привязки Binding, ни DataTable.**

Создал Главную форму с DataGridView, которая берёт данные из таблицы: **Plan_db** в БД и соответственно в таком же формате таблица выводится в datagridview. (все колонки datagridview, как на прикреплённой картинке). (Например, Преподаватель Иванов ведёт два предмета в 3 семестре , один предмет 126 часов , а второй допустим 80 часов).

Далее создаю следующую форму с textbox' ами (как на прикреплённой картинке) ,

в textbox "Преподаватель" хочу ввести фамилию и инициалы преподавателя Иванова, который уже есть в БД и datagridview, в textbox "Семестр" хочу ввести цифру семестра в котором Преподаватель ведёт несколько предметов и нажимаю кнопку "Подсчитать" и хочу что бы в textbox' е "Итоговая часовая нагрузка" был произведён подсчёт и вывод часов.

По итогу эта форма должна подсчитать общее количество часов выбранного преподавателя в выбранном семестре по двум критериям - textbox' am, если он ведёт в выбранном семестре несколько предметов (Например: Иванов А.А., 3 семестр, Итого часов : 126 +80 = 206 часов).

Я понимаю , что нужен SQL запрос с условием на выборку из таблицы Plan_db по двум критериям (Преподаватель и Семестр) , но что то пока никак не могу свести это воедино и реализовать в коде.

Нужен простой, работающий код, который считает количество часов выбранного Преподавателя , если он ведёт в выбранном семестре , больше чем 1 предмет. Потому что мой код не работает.

Может кто-то пожалуйста помочь с примерной реализацией всего этого в коде?

**Как это по простому реализовать? Без Binding и DataTable?**

Может какие похожие на мою ситуацию примеры есть?

P.S. Возникла сложность в реализации. Как видите на картинке , форму я создал и textbox-ксы в ней тоже , а также кнопку. Но это всё не работает. Я только примерно знаю что нужно написать , что бы это всё заработало, а именно: нужен SQL запрос на выборку по условию (Преподаватель и Семестр) . Эти данные (Преподаватель и Семестр) берутся из одной и той же таблицы , колонки которой соответствуют картинке , что я прикрепил выше, в предыдущем посте. Таблица Plan_db и в ней колонки: id, Преподаватель, Количество часов, Дисциплина, Семестр, Группа, Форма контроля.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код , который я написал, но он не работает:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace Teachers_Plan2
{

    public partial class Total_Time : Form
    {
        DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();


        public Total_Time()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;   
        }

        
        private void Total_Time_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox_fio.MaxLength = 50;
            textBox_semestr.MaxLength = 50;
        }

        private void textBox_ttime_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            var logFio = textBox_fio.Text;
            var logSem = textBox_semestr.Text;

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            string querystring = $"select SUM(time_of) from Plan_db where fio = '{logFio}' and semestr = '{logSem}'";

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(querystring, dataBase.getConnection());
            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            //adapter.Fill(table);

            if (table.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                //var user = new checkUser(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString(), Convert.ToBoolean(table.Rows[0].ItemArray[3]));

                //MessageBox.Show("Часовая нагрузка подсчитана!", "Успешно!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                //Form1 frm1 = new Form1(user);
                //this.Hide();
                //frm1.ShowDialog();
                //this.Show();
            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Часовая нагрузка не подсчитана!", "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В чем именно возникла сложность? в составлении SQL или еще в чем? если в SQL  то приложите схемы таблиц

Comment: Не пишите дополнительную информацию в комментариях. Вместо этого редактируйте сам вопрос, а комментарии удалите.

Comment: я бы заменил текстовые поля "преподаватель" и "семестр" на "выпадушки" (dropdown list) - просто потому, что при этом нельзя сделать опечатку в фамилии, и получить нулевой результат. Заодно попрактикуетесь в SQL запросах с distinct и order by

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217 - несколько мыслей о классе, наподобие вашего `Database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по Вашему коду, Вам нужна просто работа с SQL, и получение
результатов выполнения некотрых запросов.

При этом схема вложенности разных SQL-сущностей довольно простА:

`SqlConnection`, в него вложена `SqlCommand`, в комманд пихаем параметры и получаем данные последством `DataReader` (в случае множественных данных) или при помощи `ExecuteScalar` в случае, если надо получить одну цифИрь.

Кроме того, логично не заставлять пользователя писать данные в текстбокс, а дать ему возможнсоть выбора.

Но во многих примерах по работе с SQL сразу приводят пример с адаптером - фактически, "прослойкой", которая наполняется данными из базы, а потом с ней же связывются "потребители данных" на стороне клиента. И у Вас в коде следы работы с адаптером - есть. А он здесь не нужен.

Из своего примера я это исключил полностью, как лишнюю сущность.

Учтя это, я немного переписал Ваш код, фактически - сделал небольшой новый проект.

Он доступен [здесь](https://github.com/junecat/VariousExamples/tree/main/SqlLearnDemo), или Вы можете загрузить репку командой `git clone git@github.com:junecat/VariousExamples.git` и посмотреть в папочку `SqlLearnDemo`

Проект работает с одной таблицей, все запросы - синхронные, никакой лишней оптимизации, только простотА, только хардкор :-)

Вот как выглядит окно приложения:
[image: окно]

Таблица БД:

[image: таблица]

И - вот он, основной код:

```
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace SqlForLearn
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                Shown += Form1_Shown;
                button1.Click += Button1_Click;
            }

            private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    const string sqlCalc = "SELECT SUM(time_of) FROM Plan_db WHERE fio=@fio AND semestr=@semestr";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCalc, cn))
                    {
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@fio", DbType.String).Value = comboBox1.SelectedItem;
                        cmd.Parameters.Add("@semestr", DbType.Int32).Value = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
                        var rez = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                        textBox1.Text = rez.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }

            const string sqlConnectionString = "Password=rem;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=davydov;Initial Catalog=ExperimentsDB;Data Source=172.19.110.215";

            private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // заполняем выпадающие списки - преподавателей и семестров
                using ( SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    const string sqlSelPeoples = "SELECT DISTINCT fio FROM Plan_db ORDER BY fio";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelPeoples, cn))
                    {
                        comboBox1.Items.Clear();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while(reader.Read())
                            {
                                comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0));
                            }
                        }
                        if (comboBox1.Items.Count > 0)
                            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }

                }

                using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    const string sqlSelSemestr = "SELECT DISTINCT semestr FROM Plan_db ORDER BY semestr";
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelSemestr, cn))
                    {
                        comboBox2.Items.Clear();
                        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                        {
                            while (reader.Read())
                            {
                                comboBox2.Items.Add(reader.GetInt32(0));
                            }
                        }
                        if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
                            comboBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Теперь пара замечаний.

В Form1_Shown() происходит заполнение "выпадушек" - комбо-боксов, содержащих имена преподавателй и номера семестров.

В SQL запросах используются формальные параметры, вместо вставки текста в запрос. Вставка текста из поля ввода чревата sql injection, а у меня в примерах все sql запросы - это const. Добавление параметров сделано через `Add()`, а не через `AddWithValue()`

Что не очень хорошо.

У меня прописан пароль к БД прямо в програме.Вы его видите :-)

Таблица `Plan_db` - не нормализована. Логично хранить не fio, а идентификатор преподавателя, взятый из таблицы преподавателей.

**Дополнение**

После того, как в вопрос добавилась картинка с классом `Database` - можно сделать еще одно замечание:

Почему не работает код, еслине исправить строку sqlConnectionString? Потому, что эта строка - это "путь к базе данных". И у меня в строке прописан мой путь - к моей базе данных, а Вам нужно прописать путь к своей.

Класс `Database` работает, суда по всему, так: у него есть публичный метод getConnection(), который как раз возвращает объект  типа SqlConnection.

Вам нужно просто вместо

```
    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
```

писать что то вроде

```
        var databse = new Database();
        databse.openConnecton();
        using ( var cn = databse.getConnection() )
        {

             ...
```

То есть, смысл в том, что у Вас создаётся то же самое - SqlConnection - но внутри отдельного класса.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139278/discussion-on-answer-by-s-h------sql---winf).