# Вывод записей в datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server

Здравствуйте пытаюсь вывести записи в datagridview C# я пытался сделать вывод через Listbox чтобы заголовки были.
Код ниже:

```
Database database = new Database();
    SqlCommand cmd;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    public Dashboard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Dashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        database.openConnection();
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = database.getConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Format(Orders.Date,'yyyy-MM') as Dates FROM Departments INNER JOIN DepartmentLocations ON Departments.ID = DepartmentLocations.DepartmentID INNER JOIN Assets ON DepartmentLocations.ID = Assets.DepartmentLocationID INNER JOIN EmergencyMaintenances ON Assets.ID = EmergencyMaintenances.AssetID INNER JOIN Orders ON EmergencyMaintenances.ID = Orders.EmergencyMaintenancesID INNER JOIN OrderItems ON Orders.ID = OrderItems.OrderID Group By Format(Orders.Date,'yyyy-MM')";

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(dr["Dates"]);
        }
        database.closeConnection();
        loaddata();
    }
    public void loaddata()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();   
            for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
            }
        dgvEMSpending.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Фото что выводит у меня:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Фото как должно выводить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мб есть способ запросами сделать.

Comment: Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: даты берутся из бд

Comment: Для начала данные нужно получить из БД. В `SELECT` нужно добавить колонки, в которых эти значения: 42020, 15000, 9800.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217 - мои мысли по поводу никчёмности класса наподобие вашего `Database`

Comment: а как мне узнать

Comment: у меня же даты могу появляться другие

Comment: `SELECT Assets.Name, Orders.Price` - нужно получить из БД значения. Какие именно - только вам ведомо.