# как сделать установщик windows form приложения на C# к которому подключена SSMS база данных?

Tags: c#, winforms, ssms

Создана база данных в SSMS на локальном компьютере, также создано WindowsForm приложение на C#, которое выводит данные из таблиц БД. Сделал установочный файл приложения, на моем ПК устанавливается и работает как и задумано, а на ПК друга после установки запускаю приложение и не могу авторизоваться (в бд создана таблица с зарегистрированными пользователями). Понятно что приложение просто не может подключиться к базе данных, но как это решить?

Подключение  к базе данных прописано в отдельном классе. Код класса прилагается.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace test_DataBase
{
    internal class DataBase
    {

        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-GE5UCRH\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=test; Integrated Security=True");

        public void openConnection()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                sqlConnection.Open();
            }
        }

        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (sqlConnection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                sqlConnection.Close();
            }
        }

        public SqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            return sqlConnection;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Установщик создавался при помощи Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects 2022

Comment: Пк - друга подключен к вашей сети, так?

Comment: На одном Wi-Fi.

Comment: А пк на котором БД доступ для других пользователей разрешен?

Comment: Нет, доступа нету

Comment: Включил доступ, результат тот же

Comment: Опять я вижу бессмысленный класс-обёртку для соединения. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217

Comment: SSMS - это **не** база данных! Это среда для работы с БД. / СУБД, которую вы используете, называется Sql Server.

Comment: Строку соединения никогда не прописывают прямо в коде. Именно потому, что у разных пользователей она может быть разная! Читайте её из конфига. А в конфиг она заносится либо автоматически при установке приложения инсталлятором, либо при запуске спрашивается у пользователя, чтобы он указал путь к серверу СУБД.

Comment: На компьютере вашего друга тоже должен быть установлен Sql Server. Либо вручную, либо инсталлятором. При этом базы данных на разных компьютерах оказываются изолированны друг от друга и данные в них будут различаться. / Либо, если вы хотите, чтобы все пользователи работали с одной единственной СУБД, тогда нужно поднять сервер на одном из компов и через него обращаться к единой БД. А открывать прямой доступ к базе - тупиковый путь, так не делают (хотя это и возможно).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, А что такого тупикового в предоставлении доступа к базе? или пк? или серверу? Все три действа взаимозаменяемы и применимы в разных ситуациях и обстоятельствах. Не вижу причины давать подобного рода советы: "ТАК НЕ ДЕЛАЮТ". Не запрещено, а если ещё и просто, почему бы и нет. Банально для самостоятельного изучения тонкостей и возможностей всех причуд.

Answer (score 0):

"в бд создана таблица с зарегистрированными пользователями"

У вас авторизация в БД на базе учетки Windows.
Как вы прописали пользователей?
У вас домен или рабочая группа?

Просто есть подозрение, что у вас рабочая группа, а вы создали просто табличку с пользователями и в ручную проверяете авторизацию, уже после подключения. Определитесь и настроите доступ для подключения к БД сначала.

Далее вы столкнётесь с тем, что скорее всего не настроили прослушивание tcp/ip у sql server.
И не открыли порт в фаерволе.