# System.NullReferenceException: 'Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.' System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null

Tags: c#, база-данных, winforms

Разрабатываю приложение по работе с БД. Решил описать метод обновления изменений в БД

Выдает ошибку после отработки метода, я искренне не понимаю в чем дело, прошу помочь

```
    enum RoWState
{
    Existed,
    New,
    Modified,
    ModifiedNew,
    Deleted
}

private void Update()
    {
        db.openConnection();

        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            var rowState = (RoWState)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value;

            if(rowState == RoWState.Existed)
            {
                continue;
            }
            if(rowState == RoWState.Deleted)
            {
                var id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                var deletequery = $"DELETE FROM Products WHERE ID_Product = {id}";
                var command = new SqlCommand(deletequery, db.getCon());

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
        }
        db.closeConnection();
```

Comment: Опять я вижу бессмысленный класс `db`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1417206/184217 - ознакомьтесь. / Это в каком-то учебном заведении так учат? Передайте лично от меня своему преподу, что он [цензура].

Comment: `i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1`